# C# interop returning System.Access.Violation

Tags: c#, interop

I am attempting to use a C function through C# Interop and I am receiving an access violation on one function.  I have tried a number of things and I can't seem to solve this.

Here is the C code that needs to be changed into c# code:

```
 typedef struct
 {
    char SerNo[64];

    unsigned char hwVer; 

    HANDLE device; // Set by the API on return from SelectDevice()

 } DeviceT;
```

This struct is used by the following function:

```
    error = GetDevices(DeviceT *devices, unsigned int *numDevs, unsigned int maxDevs)
```

There is one other function in the C code:

```
    error = SelectDevice(DeviceT *device)
```

So I began by defining DeviceT.  I tried a few ways, but settled on this since it is simple:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

    public struct DeviceT
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
        public char[] SerNo;

        public byte hwVer;

        public IntPtr device;
    }
```

The GetDevices function was set to this:

```
    [DllImport("file.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public unsafe static extern  ErrT GetDevices([In, Out] DeviceT[] devices, uint* numDevs, uint maxDev);
```

The SelectDevices function was set to this:

```
     [DllImport("file.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public unsafe static extern ErrT SelectDevice([In, Out] DeviceT devices);
```

The code goes like this:

```
       uint numDevs = 6;
       uint maxDev = 6;
       uint chosenIdx = 0;

       DeviceT[] devices = new DeviceT[6];

       err = GetDevices(devices, &NumberOfDevices, maxDev))
```

At this point everything is correct.  The devices array has the correct information in it.

I now continue with (I just hard code select the first device)

```
       chosenIdx = 0;

       var chosenDevice = devices[chosenIdx];

       err = SelectDevice(chosenDevice);
```

This last function returns a System.Access Violation

I tried a whole bunch of things but all end up with the same result.  I suspect it has something to do with the HANDLE but I am not sure.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Btw, those `unsafes` are unnecessary

Comment: Ok.  I do not often use interop as you probably can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectDevice` takes a `DeviceT *`, but your P/Invoke signature takes a `DeviceT`. That is, you're passing in `DeviceT` by value rather than passing a pointer.

Try:

```
[DllImport("file.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern ErrT SelectDevice([In, Out] ref DeviceT devices);

err = SelectDevice(ref chosenDevice);
```

Comment: three little letters, and 3 days of work...Solved!!! Thank you !!